# Can't inherit contract from other one correctly

Tags: ethereum, solidity, openzeppelin

I have a ERC-721 smart contract defined like this

```
contract MintNFT is ERC721Enumerable, Ownable {
    constructor(string _name, string _symbol) ERC721(_name, _symbol){}
}
```

in which I mint the NFTs and few more functions. Then I have created a new contract to purchase the NFTs and manage some stuff, but it forces me to mark it as abstract no matter what I write in the contract. I defined it like this:

```
contract ManagerNFT is MintNFT, IERC721 {
   constructor(string memory _name, string memory _symbol) MintNFT(_name, _symbol){}
}
```

It throws an error saying `linearization of inheritance graph impossible` it goes away when I mark this ManagerNFT contract to abstract.
I don't know why this happens, I'm setting the constructors correctly I think, any thoughts on how to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `IERC721` name suggests, it's an interface.

So the `ManagerNFT` needs to implement all functions of the interface.

Comment: Yes, but when using ERC721 it gives the same error